# Haskell Guards and SublimeText 3

Tags: haskell, syntax, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I switched over to Sublime Text 3 but now that I was coding some Haskell in ST3 I noticed something quite odd, which is the syntax highlighting logic for guards.

As you can see, when I write it this way, it highlights the first guard in white colour and the different sign in a mix of white/magenta:

[image: Correct guards, incorrect highlighting.]

Only when I use this ***wrong*** syntax (with an equal sign after the argument) it displays correctly.

[image: Incorrect guards, correct highlighting.]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: That's almost definitely a bug in the Haskell plugin. You're best off posting an issue on their [GitHub](https://github.com/SublimeHaskell/SublimeHaskell) page rather than here. (In fact, somebody might have done that already, so you can take a look through the existing issues too.)

Comment: @TikhonJelvis It's actually with the default Haskell plugin, not with SublimeHaskell, which is a third party plugin.

Comment: @bheklilr: Interesting. It looks like there is actually an [open issue](https://github.com/SublimeHaskell/SublimeHaskell/issues/139) about syntax highlighting for guards though.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis Strange.  I'm quite sure it's from the default one though, because I had `SublimeHaskell` disabled until I checked out this problem for myself.  By enabling it and switching over to their syntax highlighting the problem went away.

Answer (score 5):

You're probably using the default Haskell syntax highlighting.  I would recommend disabling the `Haskell` package and installing `SublimeHaskell`.  Its syntax highlighting is much better, and it recognizes things like `otherwise` as being a "built-in" (it's mainly `Prelude` functions that are considered built-in).

If you're using the built-in Haskell highlighting, you can check that it's buggy by using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> shortcut.  Highlight each guard pipe individually and then hit this shortcut.  In the status bar it'll briefly show the syntax scope names associated with the region.  For the first pipe, you'll get `source.haskell meta.function.type-declaration.haskell`, and for the second you'll get `source.haskell keyword.operator.haskell`.  Using SublimeHaskell's syntax you'll get `source.haskell keyword.operator.haskell` for both pipes.  I won't say that SublimeHaskell's is perfect (try indenting an entire file after `module Name where`), but it's definitely better.  Since the syntaxes have the same name and because SublimeHaskell comes with snippets and whatnot that cover everything that the built-in does, I recommend disabling the `Haskell` plugin and only leaving `SublimeHaskell`'s syntax selectable.

Answer (score 0):

(NOT SURE!!!)
I now believe this is not a bug, instead I believe this is actually ST3's way of telling you you have non-exaustive patterns in that function.

Non-exaustive: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNZJ9.png

Exaustive: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZntOM.png

Comment: [You sure](http://i.imgur.com/vOUNnnC.png)? (I have no idea why my snip included a white region at the top of that image, but I'm too lazy to edit).

Comment: @bheklilr I'm not entirely sure, so if anyone could confirm this that would be great.